# How can I convert a string sent over UART to integer in python?

Tags: python, utf-8, avr, avr-gcc

I'm having difficulty converting a string I'm receiving over UART to the decimal version of it. I read in one byte with `port.read(1)` then print it

```
print "%s: %s" % ( time.ctime(time.time()), str)
```

This prints out the expected character that matches with the decimal value for that [ascii character](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). I'm sending known valued between 0 and 100. My issue is I can't convert this to the decimal value and print that instead of say '*' for 42. I'm pretty sure the default encoding/decoding is correct since the integer value in C is showing the correct character when received in python.

It may also help to mention the sender is an AVR microcontroller programmed in avr-gcc. I've messed around with decode('utf8'), decode("ISO-8859-1"), and decode("ISO-8859-2") but again I'm pretty sure this is not what I want. I've also tried converting the read value to a decimal with the int() function with no luck. I get.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xe4'
```

Comment: Are you looking for `ord(your_character)`? `ord("*")` is `42`. If you need to decode more than one byte, I'd use `struct.unpack`.

Answer (score 0):

python works perfectly, it is your avr code that is broken.

remember what you are sending is a byte with the value 0 to 100,
then on the python side you are treating this byte as a string, but characters are mapped through ascii or unicode character maps, so you are getting some characters, but not necessary integer:

```
 In [1]> chr(48)
 Out[1]> '0'
```

So you can change the code on the avr, so instead of one byte it will send one to three bytes, eg. '100' will consist of three bytes:

```
'\x31\x30\x30' 
# 49 48 48 - in decimal
```

or

you will convert data on the python side:

```
value = port.read(1)  # reading one byte
int_value = ord(value)

# or using struct module - there you can decode multiple values in one go
import struct

int_value = struct.unpack('B', value)[0]  # struct always is returning tuple
```

Comment: Ah. See I was also trying the struct.unpack but it was giving me the error that I it couldn't print a tuple. I wasn't sure how to handle that but it looks like if I just grab the first member that will give me the value I want. I'll have to try it out tomorrow after work now. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @wuttadowner you welcome, if this answers your question - mark it as a solution, thanks.

Comment: I have it printing integers now but am wondering if I am doing it the best way and I also don't understand the output from the program. It's very important the avr microcontroller is getting a known value because I use it to set the pwm speed. I was going for a value between 0 and 100. This is what I thought I was sending from python but what I receive back is as follows. Send 0-31 rx 224-255, send 32-63 rx 32-63, send 64 rx 224. On the avr (it's 8 bits so I don't know how I could send multiple bytes) I receive it as a uint8_t. Is my method poor if I want to deal with integers and not strings?

Comment: I would use [`Serial.print` `Serial.println`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print) from avr - to have ascii communication and new-line `\n` as separator I can watch for; and [StrToInt](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample) to parse data from python; but of course you can use a binary protocol too